# Writing a library around a type that the user defines (Rust)

Tags: rust, forward-declaration

I'm trying to write a library that has a focus on message passing. Everything centers around the `message` type, which is sent and received by various other components. However, rather than write the `message` enum myself, I want the user to define it to fit their purposes. The `message` type should be totally customizable and contain any data the user wants.  My first thought was to define a marker trait for message and use plain generics, like this,

```rust
trait Message {
}

struct Receiver<M: Message>  {
  process_message_fn: (&mut self, message: M) //user specifies when Reciver is created
  //...
}
```

The user then implements the marker type for their message.

This I believe would work, but I only want to ever have one message type. Theres lots of components like `Receiver` and they should all share the same `message` type for everything so they can all talk to each other. Is there a way to enforce that, ideally such that the user isn't having to write the `<>`'s that come with generics when it's not really generic? In C I would want to do something like a forward declaration or have the user `#define` the type, but don't really know what that would look like in rust.

Comment: I would find the library more useful if I could declare multiple message types even if I only needed one. But it could be done with macros for sure. A derive macro that only works once. That way you would need to keep the generics though.. I'll think on it tomorrow if there are no easy answers by then.

Comment: @Hadus, Generally I totally agree with you. However I'm doing an experiment with a gui library for game development, and higher level components take in messages, act on them (in a user defined way), and pass on new messages to their sub components. You could totally do this in a way that uses multiple message types, but I have a suspicion that that will be less ergonomic than having one master message type per instance of the gui. I could be totally wrong, but I want to enact this experiment to see.

Comment: *"The message type should be totally customizable [...]"* - Are you looking for [Generic Data Types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 , Not as such, no. Though that may be what it comes to if there isn't an alternative. Really, generics are a way to perform the same operation on multiple types. I on the other hand, am looking to perform operations on just one type. It's just that that type is defined by the consumer of the library rather than the library. As I say, this would likely work with plain generics, however as the library is designed to assume 1 message type, its really annoying to have to specify type arguments for basically every component, when there's only ever going to be one type argument supplied.

Comment: @DavidSullivan What about [Macros](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-06-macros.html)?

Comment: @Rabbid76 , macros seem like a promising solution to me, and Hadus has expressed confidence that it can be done with a macro. But I wouldn't know where to start with writing a macro that solves this particular problem (hence why I wrote this question hehe). If you have any ideas for how to do that I would love to take a look. Or if you need more details to answer, ask and I'll edit the question.

Comment: @DavidSullivan I thought we could use a proc macro to rename the user defined enum to `Message` and move it into `message.rs`. In its place put a `pub type PrevMessageName = message_crate::Message;`. Then in the message crate use `include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/message.rs"));`. It worked but badly because the `include!` in `message_crate` happens before any code in the user's crate would execute. Even `build.rs` happens after it. I am not sure there is any way around this unfortunately. By not being good I mean we have to run `build` twice after `cargo clean` or editing the enum.

Comment: I don't get why this global restriction is necessary. Wouldn't these structs have to interact in some way, which would require they all use the same message type?

Comment: @Johann150, to me it seems inappropriate (as well as a lot of extra pointless code) to write the library as if it is generic (ie, can be used with multiple types) when it only works with one type at a time, just one that the user defines rather than the library. In c it would be pretty easy to do this with a define or simply a void pointer or multiple other ways. Obviously Rust isn't C, and wants something more type safe, but I would have thought there would be a macro that can solve this problem.